# Center a inline-block div that contains floating items

Tags: html, css

Sorry if I posted something similar to other questions, but actually I needed solution. Well what I am trying to do is am creating gallery of images. So I have images of 200px, each image is block. So in order to center those image according to screen-sizes I am trying to wrap those images inside other div(i.e. inline-block). But its not ready to move in center.

I also want to mention that I am using this within a container.

```css
.gallery{
    display:inline-block; /* I am not sure what to do here */
}
.thumbnail{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:block;
}
.thumbnail img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:5px solid white;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.gallery-item{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
.clearfix:after{
    clear:both; 
}
.clearfix:after, .clearfix:before{
    display:table;
    content: " ";
}
.clearfix:after{
    content:" ";
    height:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="thumbnail gallery-item">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail gallery-item">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail gallary-item">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail gallery-item">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: actually i added and removed things and it worked now :D..
I made inline-block to thumbnail and removed float from gallary-item also removed clearfix and text-align:center worked for me....
 will appreciate to see your way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `float` property if you want elements to be centered.

```css
.gallery {
    font-size: 0; /*fix for white space */
    text-align: center;
}
.thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.thumbnail img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ntbh1rmk/

Answer (score 0):

well since i need 50 reputation to comment (very stupid restriction in my opinion).. i was going to ask why you have 100% for width and height, then add 5px padding to it? isn't that like making it 100% + 10PX?

```
.thumbnail img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:5px solid white;
    border-radius:5px;
```

maybe it's just how i'm being taught... (i'm in CSS class now).. but thats always been a bad thing.